# Big numbers and long loops in matlab?

Tags: matlab, bigdata

How can I store a matrix with 2^100 rows in MatLab! it is my search space and I really need to do it .
In your opinion, is it possible ? if yes, please help me that how can i do it?

Comment: Please at least provide some examples of what you did try.

Comment: ~10^9 Terrabytes, that's impossible.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Please elaborate on "I really need to do it".  Give us more info on the search space.  Why does it have to be in a monolithic block like this, as opposed to a pipeline of generated data?  Why is MatLab necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2<sup>100</sup> is about 10<sup>30</sup>, which is much too large for you to fit in memory - so you won't be able to store this matrix.

A couple of alternatives that you might want to think about -

1. Are many of the entries in the matrix zero? If so, you could consider using a [sparse matrix](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) which is much more memory efficient.
2. Do you need to be able to access the rows in an arbitrary order, or sequentially? If sequentially, you can generate the rows on an as-needed basis (perhaps in blocks of ten thousand at a time)
3. Do you need to look at all the rows at all? If not, perhaps you can define a function which generates the entries on the fly, as they are requested.

Comment: For such large data, even a sparse matrix is impossible. `2^48-1` is the maximum number of rows / columns supported.